# MS Edge support crossorigin attribute?

Tags: html, cross-domain, cors, microsoft-edge

I am trying to load riot.js tag file. I had a cross domain issue but fixed it by crossorigin attribute on the script tag.
It is working for all of the browsers except on Microsoft Edge.
There, getting this error:
"... not found in Access-Control-Allow-Origin header"

Anyone knows if MS Edge support the crossorigin attribute?

Comment: It looks like you proved it does not ... Why don't you setup classic CORS ? You should show some code or describe your setup.

Comment: Relatedly, Edge 14 has a serious bug when there is a crossorigin attribute on a script element. It sometimes will not execute the script, even though Edge doesn't technically support the crossorigin attribute (https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/9299606/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Microsoft Edge currently does not support the `[crossorigin]` attribute on script tags. If you would like to see support added, [please consider voting for this feature on UserVoice](https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/257854-microsoft-edge-developer/suggestions/11286087-support-the-crossorigin-cors-settings-attribute). You can track platform additions on [the Microsoft Edge Status resource](https://dev.windows.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/status/).